# Cadence Long Running Child Workflows

Tags: go, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

For long running activities we can use heartbeats to notify whether the activity is running or dead.

We have a workflow that invokes multiple child workflow with some params based on grouping which the parent workflow generates. The child-workflows are long running workflows.
Is there a way to have similar heartbeats sent from child workflows, as these workflows are long running with timeout set as a few hours ? Or rather what is the way to notify the child workflow is running ?

We are using the go-client for implementing the workflows.

Comment: Can we get some more detail here - what is "go-client", what does "workflow" mean in your context, what sort of heartbeat/timeout are we talking about, are the children separate processes and if so how do they communicate with the parent - any details you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: @adrian I would recommend checking out cadenceworkflow.io to get answers to your questions. In the context of the Cadence Workflow the question is absolutely legitimate.

Comment: @MaximFateev there should be enough context in the question to answer it if you want community volunteers to answer it for free.

Comment: @Adrian It is exactly what I'm doing. Or only questions that can be answered with 0 context can be submitted to this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long running activities heartbeat to ensure their timeout in case of a worker failure.

Workflow worker failure doesn't lead to workflow failures. So heartbeating is not necessary.